# jetty-http issue on camel-jetty-starter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-camel

I got this vulnerability on my gradle.build,

```
 jetty-http-9.4.46.v20220331.jar | Reference: CVE-2022-2047 | CVSS Score: 2.7 | Category: CWE-20 | In Eclipse Jetty versions 9.4.0 thru 9.4.46, and 10.0.0 thru 10.0.9, and 11.0.0 thru 11.0.9 versions, the parsing of the authority segment of an http scheme URI, the Jetty HttpURI class improperly detects an invalid input as a hostname. This can lead to failures in a Proxy scenario.
```

It's coming from this,

```
implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-jetty-starter:3.14.5'
```

For when I check the gradle dependencies,

```
--- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-jetty-starter:3.14.5
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.6.10 -> 2.7.0 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.camel:camel-jetty:3.14.5
|    |    +--- org.apache.camel:camel-support:3.14.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.camel:camel-http-common:3.14.5
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.camel:camel-http-base:3.14.5
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.camel:camel-support:3.14.5 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.camel:camel-cloud:3.14.5 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.camel:camel-support:3.14.5 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.camel:camel-attachments:3.14.5
|    |    |         +--- org.apache.camel:camel-support:3.14.5 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0
|    |    +--- org.apache.camel:camel-jetty-common:3.14.5
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.camel:camel-cloud:3.14.5 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.camel:camel-http-common:3.14.5 (*)
|    |    |    \--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0 -> 4.0.1
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.4.46.v20220331
|    |    |    +--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0 -> 4.0.1
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.46.v20220331
|    |    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.46.v20220331
|    |    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.46.v20220331
|    |    |    |         \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.46.v20220331
|    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.46.v20220331 (*)
```

I tried to add this before or after,

```
    implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-jetty-starter:3.14.5'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:11.0.11'
```

But eclipse will always give errror on unresolved dependency on jetty-http.

Answer (score 0):

I put all the org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xxx:9.4.48.v2022062 (hope this version stay no vulnerability).  It's not xxx, what ever you see on your dependencies, you have to add it there like jetty-(io/server/servlet/serverts/etc). Take note of the serverlet/servlets too.

Actually, can you just put xxx instead of putting all the dependency listed, I tried it didn't work.